# Creating an object with the interface name vs class name in C#

Tags: c#, oop

What is the benefit of creating an instance of an object using the Interface's name?

Let's say I have an Interface called ISampleInterface, and a class called Customer that implements ISampleInterface. **What is the difference between creating an object like this:**

```
ISampleInterface customer = new Customer();
```

and this:

```
Customer customer = new Customer();
```